# Flutter module get dependencies used into another module

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-module

I'm developing a Flutter project to study modularization. So, for the first time, I'm setting the project with core, design and feature modules, besides the project module. I'm gonna use provider for dependency injection and state management and mockito for testing, and, like in Android development, I tried to put these dependencies inside core module, and my feature module uses this core module. But inside my feature module I cant access either, mockito and provider. There is a way to do that?

this is my feature module pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  core:
    path: ../core
  design_system:
    path: ../design_system
  network:
    path: ../network
```

and this is my core module pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  provider: ^5.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  mockito: ^5.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to `export` the packages from a file in the core module. As `mockito` is a dev dependency you cant export it, but you can add it as a dev dependency in the other project.

in core/core.dart

```dart
export 'package:provider/provider.dart'
export 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart'
```

For a real-world use case take a look at the [material](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart) or [cupertino](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/cupertino.dart) packages in the flutter framework github repository

Comment: I tried and it worksssss! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :). If this answer helped you , consider marking it as the accepted answer, so we can help others on the StackOverflow Community with the same question.

Comment: I'd tried, but this is a new account. Thank you again!!!!